# For loop for creating and saving Raincloud plot in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, plot, violin-plot

I have a dataset that consists of 18 samples (A, B....etc) measured across 100-time points for 10 variables which are in columns. Each sample has 5 replicates. something like this

Sample  Replicate Timepoint Col1...Col10
A         1
A         2
A         3
B
B
B
....

I want to create a half-violin plot for every replicate of a sample. Every replicate should go side by side for each time point and I want each sample to be in a separate row which I think can be done by sns.FacetGrid(~Replicate).

I am just wondering if someone can help with this. It's going to be a huge plot but for the purpose of exploring data seems good.

Thanks

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBIhM.png)

Comment: Please give it a try yourself and if you run into issues getting your code to work, post your code with a specific question. SO is here to help you with those kinds of issues, not to write your code for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, Sorry Im new to python and my code is not that nice. I am sure others can help.

Comment: col=df_x.columns
df1=df_x.astype(float)

for i in enumerate(df1.columns):
    sns.set(style="darkgrid")
    print(i)
    g= sns.FacetGrid(df1, row = df1["Sample"], height = 5,  aspect= 20, hue="Replicate")
    g = g.map_dataframe(pt.RainCloud, x = df1["Timepoint"], y = df1[i],
       data = df1, orient = "h",palette = "Set2", bw = 0.2, width_viol = 0.3,  alpha = .1, dodge = True, pointplot = False)
    g.fig.subplots_adjust(top = 0.75)
    g.add_legend()
    #plt.figure()
    #plt.plot(df1["Timepoint"],df1[i])
    plt.show()